# What is the limit of $\frac{cos(1/x)}{x}$ when $x$ tends to Zer0?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I really need some help for this question because after I've attempt it, it seems to me every way fails to transfer this into any of the "famous" limits of trigonometric functions that I know. Then I tried to go with the geometric definitions but also with no luck. Now I don't even where to start. Can anyone help me?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Numerically plotting the function is always a good place to start. It should at least give a hint as to whether there *is* a limit, and if so, what it *should* be.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint:

Consider the limit of $\cos(1/x_n)/x_n$ as $n \to \infty$ with $x_n = 1/(2n\pi)$ and $x_n = 1/ (\pi/2 + 2n\pi)$.

Comment: @Davista: You would say the limit does not exist. In the first case the subsequence diverges to $+\infty$.  In the second case it converges to $0$.  So $\pm \infty$ and $0$ are possible for subsequences.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** Let $u = \frac1x$, so your limit becomes
$$\lim_{u \to \pm \infty} u \cos u.$$

Answer (score 0):

**Not really an answer** but related: the function $$f(z) = \exp(1/z), z\in\mathbb{C}$$ is a famous example of a function having an **essential singularity** at $z = 0$. That means by the famous Casorati-Weierstrass and [Picard's theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_theorem) it will take all possible complex values in every neighbourhood of $0$ and that behaviour will not change no matter how many times we multiply or divide with $z$.